# Gas prices for code execution

Tags: gas, gas-price

I am currently looking for the costs to execute a simple "Hello World" contract, where would I be able to find or estimate that?

I have tried some googling but to no avail.

Br
NN

Comment: What is the context: are you using Ethereum Wallet/Mist or is it from an app ?

Comment: Essentially how much it would cost to deploy it on the chain. Whatever is cheaper, I am a little unsure why that should matter though.

Comment: Because from a js app you can use web3.eth.estimateGas(), with a compiled code. If you are pasting code into Ethereum wallet, then it does tell you the gas estimate..